# Missing Gender in Magento API v2 customerCustomerList

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, magento, soap

I'm trying to implement the Magento Soap API and everything works fine. However, when retrieving the customer list, the gender field is missing.

I'm connecting trough a web reference and tried to add the gender field to the WSDL-definition of customerCustomerEntity. I tried the following:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="customer_gender" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="gender" type="xsd:string" />
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="gender" type="xsd:int" />
```

The fields are visible but contain no data. Am I missing something or is it impossible to retrieve the gender using V2 of the Soap API?

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: See this http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html You can not get Gender information directly. You need to override customerCustomerList method

Comment: Thank you! I noticed it's not available there and if I want to use the customerCustomerInfo method, it is not available. Any idea how I can override customerCustomerList with .NET?

Comment: FYI, I'm using Magento Go so I'm not able to access the source...

Comment: I you are ready to get the customer gender information for all the customers using  customerCustomerInfo  method I can help you.Because for the customerCustomerList you do not have code access.

Comment: I can use customerCustomerEntity to loop through the customerCustomerList. The customerCustomerInfo however is not available. I have a simple solution but that's not the best way. Using filters to first get customerCustomerList for gender Male, then for gender Female and lastly for unassigned values.

Comment: What do you mean by " customerCustomerInfo however is not available." We have this method in MAgento SOAP api.